# What is the maximum runs allowed to take by running between the wickets?

Tags: rules, cricket

What is the maximum number of runs allowed to take by running between the wickets per ball including overthrows in international cricket?

If a batsman doubted that he or his partner didn't get reach any of the runs, are they allowed to run more than the maximum number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit to the amount of runs that can be scored off a single ball. Any runs scored as a result of fielding side's overthrows will get added. You can read a bit more about this on [Wikipedia's article about overthrows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overthrow_%28cricket%29).

If in the case of a ball being lost in the field (in high grass or something similar), the fielding side can invoke [Law 20](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-20-lost-ball), which will award the batting side all the runs they scored from running between the wickets.